# How to display rows or select rows in pandas where any of its column contains NAN

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

My table:

```
Ram  Shyam Kamal
2    nan   4
1    2     5
8    7     10
```

I want to select or display the first row? How should I do that.

```
Ram  Shyam Kamal
2    nan   4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `df` be your dataframe, you can:

```
df = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

This returns:

```
   Ram  Shyam  Kamal
0    2    NaN      4
```